# Caliburn Micro Listbox move item up or down

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn

I've built an UI following this [example](http://www.programmersedge.com/post/2011/06/09/CaliburnMicro-WPF-Double-Click-Event.aspx#.VPfTqy57uv-)... and would like to add two buttons to re-order listbox selected item (Move up - Move Down) in the "There" list. Any ideas as to do this using Caliburn Micro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a property for `SelectedThereItem` and bind it in `ThereList`:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ThereList" SelectedItem="{Binding ThereSelectedItem}" ... />
<!-- Add buttons for ThereMoveUp and ThereMoveDown - use Caliburn naming convention -->
<Button x:Name="ThereMoveUp"/>
<Button x:Name="ThereMoveDown"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private Person _thereSelectedItem;
public Person ThereSelectedItem
{
    get { return _thereSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _thereSelectedItem = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ThereSelectedItem);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanThereMoveDown);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanThereMoveUp); 
    }
}

// Add event method handlers for ThereMoveUp/Down
public bool CanThereMoveUp { get { return _thereSelectedItem != null; } }
public void ThereMoveUp
{
    // Logic to move up
}

public bool CanThereMoveDown { get { return _thereSelectedItem != null; } }
public void ThereMoveDown
{
    // Logic to move down
}
```

Comment: Great... I had most of that coded up already... I missed the SelectedItem binding on ListBox.... thanks for your help.

Comment: PS... I take it that the CanThereMoveUp/Down provides a false return value if _thereSelectedItem == null to implement in move up/down logic?

Comment: The `CanThereMoveUp`/`Down` properties will disable the button when the return value is false. I added the NotifyOfPropertyChange to raise the event in case the button needs to be enabled or disabled.